# How to receive bytearray in php from flex mobile

Tags: php, actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex3, flex4.5

I am sending the bytearray from flex to the php using post but in the php i am unable to receive bytearray.can any one please help me how to receive the bytearray. I have looked all the posts here but  i didn't find the solution. Can any one please help me how to receive bytearray in php.

This is the flex code

```
var jsonRequest:URLRequest = new URLRequest(url);
jsonRequest.method = URLRequestMethod.POST;
    fileData = ModelLocator.getInstance.photoByteArray;//Byte Array
    var postData:Object = new Object();
    postData.title = "random title";
    jsonRequest.contentType = "multipart/form-data; boundary=" + UploadPostHelper.getBoundary();
    jsonRequest.data = UploadPostHelper.getPostData(fileName, fileData, postData);
    jsonRequest.requestHeaders.push(new URLRequestHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache"));
    var jsonLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
    jsonLoader.load(jsonRequest);
```

But in php how to receive this i have tried with file_get_contents('php://input'); but i am receiving null value.
Please tell me where i am doing wrong.

Comment: Have you checked `$_FILES`?

Comment: Hi Josh Thanks for your reply I have given $_FILES now i am getting the file data successfully but problem is i am not getting the postData "random title" which i have sent from the flex.

Comment: Thanks Josh its working perfect now. To retrieve image i have used $_FILES to get the extra params i have used $_post.